# fbconnect logout is not working perfectly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, fbconnect

i have integrated Fbconnect in LoginViewController.I want to logout the session from another view controller .. How i can do this ?

I tried this ..

```
LoginViewController *obj1 = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];     
[obj1._session logout];
[obj1._session.delegates removeObject: self];
```

It  removing the session..But wen i go to LoginViewController the button is showing logout.But when i quit application and run it, the image is  updated.

In LoginViewController i have

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController  <FBDialogDelegate, FBSessionDelegate, FBRequestDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
    IBOutlet FBLoginButton* _loginButton;
    FBSession* _session;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) FBSession *_session;
```

and am synthesizing it  @synthesize _session;

....What else i have to do ?

Somebody please help me..am very new to Iphone application and objective c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer ..My Friend helped me.. i want to share it...

simply

> ## import "FBConnect.h"

in ur second view controller

then .......

> FBSession *session = [FBSession
> session];   [session logout];

It works fine

Comment: How to import "FBConnect.h" ? I mean, Is there any link to download FBconnect.h file?

Answer (score 0):

-(void)clickfb:(id)sender
{

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in
     [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}

 [self showLoggedOut:YES];
```

}

- (void) showLoggedOut:(BOOL)clearInfo {
  //[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
  //    // Remove saved authorization information if it exists and it is
  //    // ok to clear it (logout, session invalid, app unauthorized)
      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      if (clearInfo && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]) {
          [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
          [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
          [defaults synchronize];
  //
  //        // Nil out the session variables to prevent
  //        // the app from thinking there is a valid session
          AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
          if (nil != [[delegate facebook] accessToken]) {
              [delegate facebook].accessToken = nil;
          }
          if (nil != [[delegate facebook] expirationDate]) {
              [delegate facebook].expirationDate = nil;
          }
      }

}